# Issues getting chromedriver to work on Ubuntu AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having problems getting chromedriver to run on an AWS EC2 instance, using Ubuntu. As you can see from the image below, I've used FileZilla to drop chromedriver into my remote Ubuntu site, in the same folder as the Python script itself.  I've then modified my python code to access the chromedriver from Ubuntu server, rather from my local path:

```
options = Options()
driverLocation = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
executable_path=r'/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/chromedriver 4')
driverLocation.quit()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BandsInTown_Scraper_SF.py", line 33, in <module>
    driverLocation = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/chromedriver 4')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/chromedriver 4'
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `chromedriver\ 4` or remove the space from the filename.

Comment: still no luck.  re-naming to chromedriver4 with no space still gives the error: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error:  And, chromedriver\ 4 still gives an error: executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Did you changed the filename in source?

Comment: Yes, I tried:   driverLocation = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/chromedriver\ 4')

Comment: And, driverLocation = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/chromedriver4')

Comment: Tried to add the webdriver to PATH as it says?

Comment: I beleive the issue is that ubuntu doesn't support chromedriver.